# Is it possible to show different Pushpin for 2 different contact with same postcode?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, bing-api, pushpin

Is it possible, that if we have two pins in the same location (e.g same postcode) that we can show both pins and allow the hover over information to be shown. Currently only 1 pin and hover over information is shown. I can see only one pushpin. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Natively no. What you can do quite simply is to detect that there are more than one location on the same point and handle it by yourself and present an adapted result on the map control:

- Display two elements that you position just close enough from the original location by a certain amount
- Merge the two information in the infoboxes, so you display only one elements but with a merged details in the infobox that will be displayed on mouse over

You might be interested in the terms 'clustering' and 'declustering' in your case.
Sorry I don't provide any code sample, I might search for one in my archive and update this answer. Feel free to share yours until then.

Comment: Thanks for help.. I am new to bing map. Can you please suggest any link for this or any sample?